# Dump the whole HTTP communication as raw data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, dump

I wonder if it's possible to dump the whole HTTP request+response as it goes over the wire.

I don't want to get the method, the path info, the query string, the headers, the cookies, the body and whatever. I could in theory assemble the raw data myself, but then I'd need no HTTP library, right?

Moreover, I want to dump *exactly the bytes that go over the wire*.

I want the raw data like in this image

[image: http raw data]

taken from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages).

I'm using current `node.js` as a HTTP *client* with `request`. It's plain HTTP (no HTTPS).

Installing a proxy in node.js would be an option, but I don't insist on a library. I could imagine to wrap the socket read and write functions, but I can't see how to get to the socket used.

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?

Comment: @Sid No. I'm currently busy with other parts. If I get no solution, I'll use server-side dumping (which I know how to do).

Comment: I use `ngrep` to investigate network traffic.

Answer (score 8):

The Request module returns augmented native objects.  The return value is an augmented `http.ClientRequest` object (kind of), and the callback is provided an augmented `http.IncomingMessage` as the second argument.  You can use the various properties to reconstruct the response, but you can't get it directly from here.  The native http API that Node provides abstracts away the raw response.

(Docs for `IncomingMessage` and `ClientRequest` are here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

More interestingly, these are both abstractions over `net.Socket`.  If you use the native `http` API, you can listen to this `Socket` before you send a `ClientRequest` (with `.end`).  This will give you a `Buffer` containing the HTTP response.

```
let http = require("http");
let nativeRequest = http.get({
    host: "google.com"
}); //get a ClientRequest object
nativeRequest.on('socket', function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function (data) { console.log(data.toString()); });
});
nativeRequest.end();
```

It doesn't look like this enables you to snoop on the outbound request, but it works great for the response.

Moving back up the chain of abstraction, this works fine with Request. I'll skip the snippet because it's almost identical to both the prior and the upcoming.

To get the request, we can poke around in the internals of a Socket to see if there's something we can abuse.  `Object.keys(socket)` returns the following array:

```
[
   "connecting",
   "_hadError",
   "_handle",
   "_parent",
   "_host",
   "_readableState",
   "readable",
   "domain",
   "_events",
   "_eventsCount",
   "_maxListeners",
   "_writableState",
   "writable",
   "allowHalfOpen",
   "destroyed",
   "_bytesDispatched",
   "_sockname",
   "_pendingData",
   "_pendingEncoding",
   "server",
   "_server",
   "parser",
   "_httpMessage"
]
```

And, indeed, if we poke at the suspicious looking `_pendingData`, we can view the request before it is sent:

```
let request = require('request');

let req = request("http://google.com", function (e, r, d) {});
req.on('socket', function (socket) {
    console.log("========\nRequest\n========")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(socket._pendingData, null, 3));
    console.log("========\nResponse\n========");
    socket.on('data', function (data) { console.log(data.toString()); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the request headers sent as the reponse

```
 const http = require("http")

function getRawHeader(req, res) {
    const httpVersion = req.httpVersion
    let str = `${req.method.toUpperCase()} ${req.url} HTTP/${httpVersion}\n`
    for (let i = 0; i < req.rawHeaders.length; i = i + 2) {
        str += `${req.rawHeaders[1]}  : ${req.rawHeaders[i + 1]}\n`
        console.log(i)
    }
    let written = false
    req.on("readable", (chunk) => {
        const data = req.read()
        if (!written) {
            res.write(str)
            res.write("\n")
        }
        written = true
        if (data) res.write(data)
    })

}

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    getRawHeader(req, res)
    req.on("end", () =>res.end())
}).listen(7200, () => console.log("server f is running"))
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough about the role of nodejs: It's the client talking to my (java) server. I'm unsure if your code could be adapted. I'm also unsure if using `rawHeaders` guarantees that nothing gets missed (e.g., cookies, basic auth, ...) - I only know a little about these internals. I also want to avoid any differences from the really sent/received raw data as they might be relevant one day (e.g., the spaces before colons in headers could drive the header size over the 8 kB limit....).

Answer (score 0):

`http.request` has also option to pass your own connection (`createConnection`). You can use this option to provide your own created connection, which is "piped()" to a logger transform stream.

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');
const http = require('http');
const agent = new http.Agent();
let nativeRequest = http.get({
    host: 'google.com',
    createConnection: options => {
        let connection = agent.createConnection(options);
        let logger = new Transform({
            transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
                console.log(chunk.toString());
                connection.write(chunk, encoding, callback);
            },
            flush: () => {},
        });
        connection.pipe(logger);
        return logger;
    },
});
nativeRequest.on('socket', function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
});
nativeRequest.end();
```

### Some notes

I tried to implement `PassThrough` stream instead of the `Transform`. That gave me HTTP parse error when I piped PassThrough stream to the connection. I don't know why to be honest.

It's important to include the `flush: () => {}`, from the documentation

> This will be called when there is no more written data to be consumed, but before the 'end' event is emitted signaling the end of the Readable stream.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback